# Save the plots as JPEG or PDF from jupyter notebook with R Kernel

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I'm having a trouble with saving the plots as jpeg or pdf format from **R** kernel of Jupyter Notebook.

Here's the code,

```
pdf("Hatdog.jpeg")
plot(x,y, col="green")
dev.off()
```

I was wondering why the image is corrupted, which when I tried to open the actual file, it states that *It looks like we don't support this file format.*

[image]

Anyone having the same issue? How did you solved it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are saving a pdf file with a -.jpg extension?
To save as a jpeg:

```
# 1. Open jpeg file
jpeg("rplot.jpg", width = 350, height = 350)
# 2. Create the plot
plot(x = my_data$wt, y = my_data$mpg,
     pch = 16, frame = FALSE,
     xlab = "wt", ylab = "mpg", col = "#2E9FDF")
# 3. Close the file
dev.off()
```

To save as a pdf:

```
# Open a pdf file
pdf("rplot.pdf") 
# 2. Create a plot
plot(x = my_data$wt, y = my_data$mpg,
     pch = 16, frame = FALSE,
     xlab = "wt", ylab = "mpg", col = "#2E9FDF")
# Close the pdf file
dev.off()
```

(from http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/creating-and-saving-graphs-r-base-graphs)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, when I opened the file, this message shows *we can't open this file*. Note, my operating system is windows 10.

Comment: In your first not commented line, the 350 of height shouldn't be in "", is that right?